# Tagging a specific Selenium Node (without modifying browser version)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid

When running multiple tests using Selenium Grid, it picks a node randomly from a pool of available nodes that match a defined criteria (like browser type and version). There is often a need to run a test on a specific node but there is no direct way to do that. One of the workarounds is to rename the browser version on one of the nodes to some unusual value and then launch the tests with the matching target browser capabilities. That approach works fine however it is slightly inconvenient as it requires to log into that node each time such change is required and when you want to re-include this node into the pool again.

Hence I wonder whether there is another way that this can be achieve? Perhaps there are other target browser capabilities that might be used to select a specific node?

Comment: It's been a really long time since I've messed with grid... is there some custom property that you can put on each node? What is it about a specific node that makes you want to run a script on it vs the other nodes? Maybe specify that as the custom property, etc.?

Comment: @JeffC This is exactly what I am asking :)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/working-with-a-custom-capability-matcher-in-the-grid/. See the crazyNodeName: Rambo example. Isn't that essentially what you are looking for?

Comment: @JeffC Yes, that's interesting. I will have a read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this which looks like what you are trying to do.

https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/working-with-a-custom-capability-matcher-in-the-grid/

Basically they are creating a custom configuration for the node and they give an example. It looks like you would just add a property, like the `"crazyNodeName" : "Rambo"` example below, with whatever you want.

```
{
    "capabilities":
        [
          {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "crazyNodeName": "Rambo"
          }
        ],
    "configuration":
    {
      "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
      "maxSession": 5,
      "port": 5555,
      "host": ip,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 5000,
      "hubPort": 4444,
      "hubHost": ip
    }
  }
```